# Draw driving route in dataset editor

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

Is there an easy way to draw (or define by waypoints) a driving route that is snapped to road centerlines in Mapbox Studio dataset editor, like can be done in Google Maps [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t48AT.png)? I see how to draw points, lines and polygons, but no option for driving (or walking/cycling) routes.

If not, is there a suggested workaround? I see [how to import Google KML into a tileset](https://www.mapbox.com/videos/how-to/switch-from-google-maps-to-mapbox-in-90-seconds/), but the imported route is not snapped to the Mapbox roadways.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can get a navigable route using [Mapbox's Directions API Playground](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/directions/). Save the response to a file, eg navigation_route.geojson, for use in the python code snippet below.

Then one can extract a polyline from the response using the snippet below which saves the extracted polyline to a similarly named file (eg navigation_route_parsed.geojson, below). This file can up uploaded to [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio) as a dataset and then imported to a map within Mapbox Studio as a layer to ultimately create a map with multiple navigable routes.

```
import json

input_file_name_prefix = 'navigation_route'
input_file_name = input_file_name_prefix + '.geojson'
output_file_name = input_file_name_prefix + '_parsed.geojson'

data = {}
with open(input_file_name) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
   
features = data["routes"][0]

coordinates = []

for leg in features["legs"]:
    for step in leg["steps"]:
        coordinates += step["geometry"]["coordinates"]

feature_collection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": coordinates
            }
        }
    ]
}

with open(output_file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(feature_collection, outfile, indent=2)
```

Comment: THANK YOU @shoeless this is perfect! Now even a non-coder like me can create driving/walking/cycling routes in Mapbox Studio...n00bs just need to install Python, and then this snippet can be executed in Terminal which creates a new .geojson that can successfully be imported by the Mapbox Dataset Editor.

I wish Mapbox would enable the creation of driving/walking/cycling polylines within the Dataset Editor – but until then, this Python snippet works great. 

Thanks again